# Build failed with error Finished with non zero exit value 3

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been experiencing this error for quite some days. I have searched and tried other solution prior to posting this question.

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.myApps"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
}
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.49'
    compile 'net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.+@aar'

    compile files('libs/acssmc-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidmarketapi-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/emvswipeapi-android-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/newrelic.android.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.47.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.47.jar')
}
```

I have identified that

```
compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.49'
```

is causing the non zero exit value 3.
After I comment it, the error is gone.
But this jdk is important and I cannot comment it.

Is there another workaround for this?

** **EDIT** **
Added Error message in hope to help solve issue.

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.android.dx.ssa.SetFactory.makeLivenessSet(SetFactory.java:91)
at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.addLiveOut(SsaBasicBlock.java:792)
at com.android.dx.ssa.back.LivenessAnalyzer.liveOutAtBlock(LivenessAnalyzer.java:199)
at com.android.dx.ssa.back.LivenessAnalyzer.handleTailRecursion(LivenessAnalyzer.java:141)
at com.android.dx.ssa.back.LivenessAnalyzer.run(LivenessAnalyzer.java:188)
at com.android.dx.ssa.back.LivenessAnalyzer.constructInterferenceGraph(LivenessAnalyzer.java:93)
at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.<init>(SsaToRop.java:82)
at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertToRopMethod(SsaToRop.java:69)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:101)
at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:297)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Comment: Have you tried commented all `compile files...` lines and `provided fileTree...` line, then add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` yet?

Comment: Ya I have tried that solution before.

Comment: Try use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'` instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

Comment: Tried it just now. Still same error after sync clean and build.

Comment: How about `'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52'`. If error still exists, try [Finished with Non Zero Exit Value 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720831/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-3). Hope this help

Comment: Tried the `'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52'` still same.
The link I have also tried. :(

Comment: I have added my answer. And if error not gone, close and reopen Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update your gradle file like this (add `packagingOptions`) :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

I have used your entire build.gradle file without any error. My envrionment:

- Android Studio 1.3.1
- Inside build.gradle (in project folder):

  ```
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
  ```

-MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testgradle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Update with "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded", try

```
dexOptions{        
    incremental true 
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
}
```

Comment: Added in the packagingOptions into the build.gradle file but it is still the same.
I added in the error message just in case it might shed some light into this issue.

Comment: I have found an answer at [GC overhead limit exceeded] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823518/com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-org-gradle-process-internal-exe), you can try